# Intersection between a set and its boundary is a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it possible to show that for a neither open nor closed subset $ A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$,  $\partial A \cap A$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $A=\mathbb{Q}$ has $\mathbb{R}$ as its boundary so $A \cap \partial A = A$ is neither open nor closed.